# Concatenation of setof type or setof record

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I use Postgresql 9.1 with Ubuntu 12.04.

In a `plpgsql` function I try to concatenate `setof` type returned from another function.

the `type pair_id_value` in question is created with `create type pair_id_value as (id bigint, value integer);`

the function that returns elementary `setof pair_id_value` (those that will be concatenated later) is this one:

```
create or replace function compute_pair_id_value(id bigint, value integer)
    returns setof pair_id_value
as $$
    listResults = []
    for x in range(0,value+1):
        listResults.append({ "id": id, "value": x})
    return listResults
$$
language plpython3u;
```

this straigth-forward plpython code should be good, for exemple the query: `select * from compute_pair_id_value(1712437,2);` returns nicely:

```
  id            | value 
 ---------------+-----------
        1712437 |         0
        1712437 |         1
        1712437 |         2
 (3 rows)
```

*this python function is fairly simple for now, for this example, but above all for my proof of concept. It will be more complex in the near future.*

The problem arises when I try to concatenate all the result tables from multiples id.

```
create or replace function compute_all_pair_id_value(id_obj bigint)
    returns setof pair_id_value as $$
declare
    pair pair_id_value;
begin
    for pair in (select compute_pair_id_value(t.id, t.obj_value) from my_obj as t where t.id = id_obj)
    loop
            return next pair;
    end loop;
    return; 
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

I receive the error: `invalid input syntax for integer "(1712437,0)"` as if it is no longer seen as a pair_id_value with two columns but as a tuple (1712437,0).

So I changed the output type of the function from setof pair_id_value to setof record... and if I execute this similar concatenation function:

```
create or replace function compute_all_pair_id_value(id_obj bigint)
    returns setof record as $$
declare
    pair record;
begin
    for pair in (select compute_pair_id_value(t.id, t.obj_value)  from my_obj as t where t.id = id_obj)
    loop
            return next pair;
    end loop;
    return; 
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

I get the error: `a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`

Trying to follow the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret):  I have tried defining the column definition in the select this way `select compute_pair_id_value(t.id, t.obj_value) as f(id bigint, value integer)`, the complete code is here:

```
create or replace function compute_all_pair_id_value(id_obj bigint)
    returns setof record as $$
declare
    pair record;
begin
    for pair in (select compute_pair_id_value(t.id, t.obj_value) as f(id bigint, value integer) from my_obj as t where t.id = id_obj)
    loop
            return next pair;
    end loop;
    return; 
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

But when launching the sql script, psql doesn't accept to create the function:
`syntax error at or near "("  select compute_pair_id_value(t.id, t.obj_value) as f(id bigint, value integer)` ... pointing the finger at the f(

Any idea how to do it properly ?

Should I consider to create temporary table to do the job ?

Comment: How is `pair_id_value` defined? With `CREATE TYPE` as a composite type?

Comment: I used the line `create type pair_id_value as (id bigint, value integer);`

Comment: Argh, it's right there in the question text. Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: I tried your answer with `return query` and the `.*` after the setof record returned by the function. But it gives me a syntax error because at or near the . of .*

Comment: Fixed based on better understanding of the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you're using is unnecessarily complex - and very inefficient. Instead of the first function use:

```
create or replace function compute_pair_id_value(id bigint, value integer)
    returns setof pair_id_value
as $$
SELECT $1, generate_series(0,$2);
$$                          
language sql;
```

or better, get rid of it entirely and write the whole operation like this:

```
-- Sample data creation:
CREATE TABLE my_obj(id bigint, obj_value integer);
insert into my_obj(id,obj_value) VALUES (1712437,2),(17000,5);

-- and the query:
SELECT id, generate_series(0,obj_value) FROM my_obj;
```

Resulting in:

```
regress=> SELECT id, generate_series(0,obj_value) FROM my_obj;
   id    | generate_series 
---------+-----------------
 1712437 |               0
 1712437 |               1
 1712437 |               2
   17000 |               0
   17000 |               1
   17000 |               2
   17000 |               3
   17000 |               4
   17000 |               5
(9 rows)
```

This exploits PostgreSQL's behaviour with set-returning functions called in the `SELECT` list. Once PostgreSQL 9.3 comes out it can be replaced with a  standards-compliant `LATERAL` query.

---

Since it turns out your question was a simplified version of the real problem, let's tackle that. I'll work with the simplified `compute_pair_id_value` above to avoid the hassle of plpython3. Here's how to do what you want:

```
SELECT (compute_pair_id_value(id,obj_value)).* FROM my_obj;
```

Result:

```
regress=> SELECT (compute_pair_id_value(id,obj_value)).* FROM my_obj;
   id    | value 
---------+-------
 1712437 |     0
 1712437 |     1
 1712437 |     2
   17000 |     0
   17000 |     1
   17000 |     2
   17000 |     3
   17000 |     4
   17000 |     5
(9 rows)
```

but again, be warned that `compute_pair_id_value` will be called more than once. This is a limitation of PostgreSQL's query executor that can be avoided in 9.3 with `LATERAL` support, but as far as I know you're stuck with it in 9.2 and below. Observe:

```
create or replace function compute_pair_id_value(id bigint, value integer)
    returns setof pair_id_value
as $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'compute_pair_id_value(%,%)',id,value;
  RETURN QUERY SELECT $1, generate_series(0,$2);
END;
$$             
language plpgsql;
```

output:

```
regress=> SELECT (compute_pair_id_value(id,obj_value)).* FROM my_obj;
NOTICE:  compute_pair_id_value(1712437,2)
NOTICE:  compute_pair_id_value(1712437,2)
NOTICE:  compute_pair_id_value(17000,5)
NOTICE:  compute_pair_id_value(17000,5)
   id    | value 
---------+-------
 1712437 |     0
 1712437 |     1
 1712437 |     2
   17000 |     0
   17000 |     1
   17000 |     2
   17000 |     3
   17000 |     4
   17000 |     5
(9 rows)
```

See how `compute_pair_id_value` is called once per output column?

There *is* a workaround: Another layer of subquery to unpack the composite type result. See:

```
regress=> SELECT (val).* FROM (SELECT compute_pair_id_value(id,obj_value) FROM my_obj) x(val);
NOTICE:  compute_pair_id_value(1712437,2)
NOTICE:  compute_pair_id_value(17000,5)
   id    | value 
---------+-------
 1712437 |     0
 1712437 |     1
 1712437 |     2
   17000 |     0
   17000 |     1
   17000 |     2
   17000 |     3
   17000 |     4
   17000 |     5
(9 rows)
```

You can use the same technique in your code if you really must `LOOP` over the results (it's slow to do that, so avoid it if you can).

Comment: I have simplified the python function, later it will perform more complex work, I need to be able to concatenate setof types/ record generated by plpython.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Ah. Things like "this is a simplified version of the real problem" are handy to mention in the original question.

Comment: as I show in the question, the output of the plpython function looks really ok.

Comment: ok I'll mention it, however, **the plpython function is in the state it IS right now**. It will be more complex in the near future, when this will work ;-)

Comment: in your answer you create a table wit you generator. In my question, at the end I ask if I should go for a temporary table. Do you think it's worth ? As I may have tens of thousands of my_obj ids... this may be worth it...

Comment: @StephaneRolland Honestly, hard to say. In cases like that I tend to build test cases with dummy data and examine their performance. `psql`'s `\timing` command is useful for this but it also records data transfer from, so the server side setting `log_min_duration_statement` (to log just server-side execution time) and the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command are very handy. BTW, answer updated with a workaround for the double execution of the function; the extra subquery appears to get optimized away so it shouldn't affect performance.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Certainly a bunch of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` commands run in a single transaction *can* be more efficient. It also depends a lot on what you're doing with the result, how much you want to re-use the result, etc. If you have a temp table you can do handy things like add indexes to it after creating it and before joining it to other tables.

Comment: I have kept your idea of a series generator, this value could be further filter by a select if I want to add complexity. However when I try almost your solution ( returns setof record instead of type pair_id_value) I get an error. I have created a new question for this

Comment: @StephaneRolland Not seeing the new question - link?