# Error: set_valued function called in context that cannot accept a set. What is it about?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I use Postgresql 9.1, with ubuntu 12.04.

Inspired by Craig's answer to my question [Concatenation of setof type or setof record](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37547/concatenation-of-setof-type-or-setof-record) I thought I would go well with using `return query`, `setof record`, and a series generator into this plpgsql function:

```
create or replace function compute_all_pair_by_craig(id_obj bigint)
    returns setof record as $$
begin
    return query select o.id, generate_series(0,o.value) from m_obj as o;     
end;
$$    language plpgsql;
```

During execution I get the error:

`ERROR: set_valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`

What is wrong ? Contrary to Craig I tell the function to return `setof record`.

I can achieve something that work doing exactly like Craig, i.e. by defining a type `create type pair_id_value as (idx bigint, value integer)` and have my plpgsql function returns a `setof of pair_id_value` instead of a `setof record`.

But even with this working solution, I still don't understand why `select id, generate_series(0,13)` alone will return a result in **two columns**... and on the contrary calling the function (returns setof pair_id_value) with `return query select id, generate_series(0,my_obj.value) from my_obj` will return a result in **only one column** which field look like this "(123123,0)" "(123123,1)" "(123123,2)" (3 rows)  which are tuples obviously.

Is it a case where a temporary table must/should be created ?

Comment: That can't be the exact text of the function you're running because it doesn't compile; there's an excess semicolon after `BEGIN` and a missing one after the `RETURN QUERY`. After correcting those errors I confirm the error when returning `record`; will explain in answer.

Comment: @CraigRinger I put the semicolon back in place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message isn't very helpful:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM  compute_all_pair_by_craig(100);
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM  compute_all_pair_by_craig(100);
```

but if you rephrase the query to call it as a proper set-returning function you'll see the real problem:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM compute_all_pair_by_craig(100);
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM compute_all_pair_by_craig(100);
```

If you're using `SETOF RECORD` without an `OUT` parameter list you must specify the results in the calling statement, eg:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM compute_all_pair_by_craig(100) theresult(a integer, b integer);
```

However, it's much better to use `RETURNS TABLE` or `OUT` parameters. With the former syntax your function would be:

```
create or replace function compute_all_pair_by_craig(id_obj bigint)
    returns table(a integer, b integer) as $$
begin
    return query select o.id, generate_series(0,o.value) from m_obj as o;     
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This is callable in SELECT-list context and can be used without creating a type explicitly or specifying the result structure at the call site.

---

As for the second half of the question, what's happening is that the 1st case specifies two separate columns in a SELECT-list, wheras the second returns a single composite. It's actually not to do with how you're returning the result, but how you're invoking the function. If we create the sample function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION twocols() RETURNS TABLE(a integer, b integer) 
AS $$ SELECT x, x FROM generate_series(1,5) x; $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

You'll see the difference in the two ways to call a set-returning function - in the `SELECT` list, a PostgreSQL specific non-standard extension with quirky behaviour:

```
regress=> SELECT twocols();
 twocols 
---------
 (1,1)
 (2,2)
 (3,3)
 (4,4)
 (5,5)
(5 rows)
```

or as a table in the more standard way:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM twocols();
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
 3 | 3
 4 | 4
 5 | 5
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Just tested, works perfect. And I like this syntax with `returns table`.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Updated with explanation of latter part of question too.

Comment: thx for the support. Now it's much much clearer.